Retaining type information when enforcing type relationship between members of a tuple, when used in Mapped type function parameter
I have types that enforce relationship between both members of a tuple within array of these tuples when passed as argument to function i.e. second member is a function that takes in a data parameter matching first member. Playground
First checking whether Tuple relationships hold:
export type TupleDataFn<Type>
    = Type extends [infer Data, infer Fn]
    ? Fn extends ((data: Data) => any)
        ? Type
        : never
    : never

A mapped type that applies the check for all members of array:
export type ArrayOfTuples<A>
    = {[K in keyof A]: TupleDataFn<A[K]>}

A test function
export const test = <H extends [any, any][]>(handler: ArrayOfTuples<H>) => {}

And finally the usage - here the parameter of function without
test([
    // I can do this explicitly and this works as expected
    ['explicit', (data: string) => {}],
    // in remaining cases, the data is 'any'
    // instead of infered types matching the first member
    ['text', (data) => {}],
    [42, (data: string) => {}],
    [{ count: 10, data: "test"}, (data) => {}]
])

Here the data parameter is always 'any' unless explicitly defined (in that case type checks work and enforce type of function parameter as expected).
Is there any way to achieve the expected behavior, where type of data parameter in function tuple member is inferred from type of first member?
Playground link trying to incorporate @jcalz code into my use case with restricted Tuple types, unable to make autocomplete work.
Updated Playground

Do you need the solution to leverage your types TupleDataFn and ArrayOfTuples because you're already using them elsewhere? Or do you simply need something that will accomplish your end goal in the test function?

No, I was just researching ways to achieve end goal of being able to pass an array of those two member tuples, with type error when those member's relation breaks, and at the same time having that function parameter type inferred automatically, without need to specify its type.

You can't currently achieve this due to ms/TS#53018. What you're doing is "inferring from mapped types" or "reverse mapped types" and the context-sensitive callback param in each property can't be inferred currently. I'd be happy to write up an answer saying as much. You'd have to work around it by using individual generic functions for each member of your array (which seems to be the approach the answer below is using). How should we proceed?

I solved this for now by changing parameter from Array of Tuples into function  type that provides helper function so you call it like fun(helper => [helper('string', str => 'result'), which is not ideal but probably option I like the most. If you think elaboration on this would be helpful to others feel free to add it and I'll accept it.

Oh, wait, maybe you don't actually the full ms/TS#53018. Does this version meet your needs? If so then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Seems like I did quite a blunder here that I somehow skipped this path towards the solution. The type in your playground results in exactly what I needed, thank you very much.

I put a Playground link at the bottom of my question, expanding a bit on your code - type checking works, I connected it with data restricting type, this works on checking types, however autocomlete doesn't work as I cant get fields of object type to show. Did I run into reverse mapped type issue again here?

Is that a followup question? If so, then can we put this one to bed before diving into it? Or is it a necessary piece to answer this current question, in which case could you [edit] the question so the issue is in plaintext and not just a playground link? Also, from that link it's not immediately obvious where you expect autocomplete to happen.  My preference here is to write up the answer I suggested first and then we can look at autocomplete stuff in a new question if it persists, but I'll wait to hear what you want to do.

I could make a new question, and put there a  working case where parameter is function returning array of tuples instead of just array of tuples to illustrate the issue better. Regarding autocomplete in new Playground - there is and Object type in union, so once I write curly braces, I need to get autocomplete options for both props, which I don't get currently. It checks and errors if the props are missing, but  never really offers them.

You could write this version maybe; my inclination to put H extends D[] causes inference to fail, so I need to write H extends any[] and then intersect each element of H with D.  Not sure if that meets your needs.

Functionality-wise this is as close as it can get to what I wanted so far it seems, the only problem is purely cosmetic (which is pretty big problem) as this completely obfuscates type in IDE, do you think any transformation to this would be possible to straighten the result up? I tried some "prettify" types but these don't seem to play nicely with intersections.

This sort of inference, where you need TypeScript to simultaneously infer generic type arguments and unannotated callback parameter types contextually, is a pain point in TypeScript. TypeScript's inference algorithm uses various heuristics that work well in a wide range of scenarios, but once you have contextual and generic types that depend on each other, the inference algorithm doesn't always find a suitable set of types, even if a human being can see how to do it.  Sometimes the inference is "partly" successful, in the sense that a contextual type might be inferred properly while a corresponding generic type argument that depends on it is not (and falls back to something less useful like unknown).
There's an open issue at microsoft/TypeScript#47599 asking for improvements in these situations, and such improvements have been happening steadily, such as microsoft/TypeScript#48538, but there will always be gaps. And the support that is there is sometimes fragile in the face of seemingly minor changes. So a technique that works in a particular case might fail in a slightly different one.
Generally speaking you might want to refactor to relieve TypeScript of the duty of having to do such simultaneous inference, such as by using builders to do things in stages instead of all at once.  But that's outside the scope of the question as asked.

For the code in the question as asked, I'd write
const test =
    <H extends any[]>(tuples: { [I in keyof H]: [H[I], (data: H[I]) => void] }) => { }

where the function is generic in H, the tuple of data types, and where the tuples parameter is a mapped tuple type over H.  So if H is [X, Y, Z], then tuples is [[X, (data: X)=>void], [Y, (data: Y)=>void], [Z, (data: Z)=>void]].  And therefore when you call test() we want TypeScript to infer H from the mapped type of tuples.
Let's try it:
test([
    ['explicit', (data: string) => { data.toUpperCase() }],
    ['text', (data) => { data.toUpperCase() }],
    [42, (data: string) => { }], // error!
    [{ count: 10, data: "test" }, (data) => { data.count }]
])

Looks good.  Here H is inferred as [string, string, number, { count: number; data: string;}]. The explicitly annotated data in the first element is fine, as before. But now the unannotated data in the second and fourth elements are also fine, and inferred as the corresponding type from H.  And the incorrectly annotated data in the third element gives the expected error.
So that all works as expected. But again, this could be fragile to minor variations in the code, as such things tend to be at the edge of TypeScript's ability to infer.
Playground link to code

Thank you for answer, I updated my second Playground with your code, and my solution that has autocompletion but wraps the array in function. If you think the array only solution of yours could have autocomplete possibility matching mine solution, I could do follow-up as discussed yesterday, but it may be beyond TS inference capacities at this time.

Based on your comment, I did find an alternative approach, although it requires the use of a helper function to define the tuples:
type Tuple<T> = [val: T, fn: (data: T) => void];
const test = (params: Tuple<any>[]) => {};
const createTuple: <T>(val: T, fn: (data: T) => void) => [T, typeof fn] = (val, fn) => [val, fn];

test([
    createTuple('explicit', (data) => { console.log(data); }), // string
    createTuple('text', (data) => { console.log(data); }), // string
    createTuple(42, (data) => { console.log(data); }), // number
    createTuple({ count: 10, data: "test"}, (data) => { console.log(data); }), // { count: number; data: string; }
]);

Essentially, using the helper function allows typescript to re-infer the types for each element of the array. Without it TS will only infer the first tuple type it finds, and will assume all further elements of the array should conform to the first one.

Thank you for suggestion, I was considering some variation of utility function for this, but I still wonder whether this can be solved entirely within the type system.
